# After several years working, my DSN Less connection now fails with Error 3125 '... not a valid name'

Tags: sql-server, odbc

My MS Access Client attaches to SQL Server tables via a DSNLess connection. It has been attaching successfully with no issues for several years, until January 14th 2023.

I now get an error 3125 with error description:'dbo.Denomination' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.

As can be seen, the table name 'Denomination' is short and contain no invalid characters. Even odder, table 'Denomination' is not the first table in my list. It is preceded by two other tables (AuditLog & lnkDBSCheck) that attach successfully.

The operating environment is: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit. Version 22H2. OS Build 19045.2486

I've tried the following to resolve the issue.

- Decompiled the MS Access Client FE
- Tried different drivers:
  'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server', 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' & 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0'
- Tried earlier versions of the Client.
  The result is always the same - Error 3125.

I'm now wondering if the issue is related to Windows updates of a few days before (on 11th Jan, though I only rebooted my workstation on the 13th). The updates were KB5022282 (cumulative update for Windows 10 Version 22H2 for x64-based Systems) & KB890830 (Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool x64 - v5.109.

I'm out of ideas on this - help!

Comment: On the SQL Server side of the fence is it possible that the (SQL/Windows) Login that you use has been edited to change its default database? But in all likelihood it's due to a Microsoft 365 update, e.g.: Using Excel/Text files from Access caused [error 3125 messages](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/error-3125-after-many-years-working-ok/1aa0e714-fbee-4d8f-88ed-80267037e935) in June/July 2022 when updating from version 2205 to 2206 .

Answer (score 0):

Run this from an administrator command prompt

```
Cd C:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun

officec2rclient.exe /update user updatetoversion=16.0.15831.20208
```

Then disable update in Microsoft Office

Original Posting
https://www.devhut.net/microsoft-office-uninstall-an-update/

Our Access program gave us the same problem.

Office Release Notes:  (This broke our DSN connection)

Version 2212: January 04
Version 2212 (Build 15928.20198)

Feature updates
Access
Enable the ability to code sign your Microsoft Access database and VBA code: This update enables the Tools/Digital Signature command within the VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) IDE (Integrated Development Environment) for current Microsoft Access database formats. Signing a database will allow VBA code in the database to be run even if Trust Center settings specify that only digitally signed code should be enabled.